# How to reset images effect onclick with CSS

Tags: html, css, vue.js

i just created an effect with polygons with VueJS and CSS. When hover on any image get the whole width and height.  What i what to do is hover the image, then when get the whole width and height reset it again into the original state. I have tried everything (Active pseudo-classes, checkbox trick, etc) but nothing works.

Here is the code online: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/funny-silence-t6wl8v?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A12%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A34%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A1%7D%5D

this is the css

```
@import "./base.css";

:root {
  font-family: Inter, system-ui, Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#app {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #111;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #222;
}

.container .clip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container .clip.clip1 {
  background: url("./img/img1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 55% 0, 20% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.container .clip.clip2 {
  background: url("./img/img2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  clip-path: polygon(55% 0, 100% 0%, 45% 100%, 20% 100%);
}

.container .clip.clip3 {
  background: url("./img/img3.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 45% 100%);
}

.container:hover .clip {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%);
}

.container .clip:hover {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container .clip:hover .content {
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

And this is the html

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="clip clip1">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Post title</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui
          recusandae fugit dolores accusamus est ex id dolor ab tenetur, non sit
          a et asperiores doloribus libero aut animi cupiditate reiciendis.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clip clip2">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Post title</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui
          recusandae fugit dolores accusamus est ex id dolor ab tenetur, non sit
          a et asperiores doloribus libero aut animi cupiditate reiciendis.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clip clip3">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Post title</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui
          recusandae fugit dolores accusamus est ex id dolor ab tenetur, non sit
          a et asperiores doloribus libero aut animi cupiditate reiciendis.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: what exactly is the issue here?

Comment: Everything looks fine - but the post title is hiding the bottom of the photo. Did you want it to be semi transparent or something?

Comment: @HarshitT I just want to reset the image into the original state (i mean, showing the firts 3 image)   on click image while hovering.

Comment: @AHaworth I just want to reset the image into the original state (i mean, showing the firts 3 image)   on click image while hovering.